# Set limits to Pageable on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I've got a

```
@ResponseBody
@Produces("application/json")
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<User> getRecentUsers(Pageable pageable,
                                    HttpServletResponse response){
    return userRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Can I set limits to the pageSize of the pageable automatically, without having to accept page and pageSize indicidually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the pageable object before passing it to findAll.

Being an interface anyway you have to build a new object with it. Something like:

```
Pageable wrapped = new PageRequest(pageable.getPage(), Math.min(pageable.getSize(), **maxsize**), pageable.getSort());
return userRepository.findAll(wrapped);
```

Comment: But that leads to much boilerplate code. Isn't there some easier way to do it apart from having a RestRepository configured with these min and max programmatically setted up?